# How to add post-processing to a tflite model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite, post-processing

I know how to create a freezed graph and use the [export_tflite_ssd_graph](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/export_tflite_ssd_graph_lib.py) - however, is it possible to add post-processing to a tflite graph?

It is not possible to freeze a tflite graph since r1.9, so the usual function won't work. So is there any workaround to add post-processing to a tflite graph when you only have the .tflite File?

Comment: Hi! Have your checked these threads on post training quantization yet ? You can optimize tflite model further using quantization.  https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/post_training_quantization     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64372279/how-to-convert-tflite-model-to-quantized-tflite-model    https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/g3doc/performance/post_training_integer_quant.ipynb